# Settings CSSvalues per mouse.x

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, position, mouse

It is this simple. I overrode the default mousemove event, and I replaced it with this:

```
function onDocumentMouseMove(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  mouse.x = (e.clientX / WIDTH) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = -(e.clientY / HEIGHT) * 2 + 1;

  var x = mouse.x + "px";
  $('#gun').css('left', x);
}
```

However, this doesn't work, the gun is just rendered as originally positioned. Please help, because I need to know basic stuff like this to be a programmer. I'm just too stupid. Maybe I need Stackoverflow just as compensation?

Thanks to all of you guys who work so hard to answer questions!

- Noah

Comment: Have you called `addEventListener` to bind `onDocumentMouseMove` to a DOM Element?

Comment: Try removing the "px". jQuery will automatically add "px"

Comment: Thanks Chris! This was probably what I needed to do, but just in case, I also reformatted the code to look like Dave's example. Case Closed, thanks everyone!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be using jQuery so you need something like;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $gun = $('#gun');
  var mouseMove = function (e) {
    $gun.css('left', e.clientX);
    $gun.css('top', e.clientY);
  }
  window.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove, false);
}
```

You will need to ensure you provide the correct CSS for the gun element so the position is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code generally would work if you declare your `WIDTH`, `HEIGHT`, `mouse` right. I made a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dawchihliou/0L00ojva/) for you so you can see the result.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  /*
   * place jquery objects & constants declarations outside of 
   * event handler so you don't redeclare them every time the 
   * event fires.
   */
  var $gun = $('#gun');
  var WIDTH = $gun.css('width').match(/\d*/)[0];
  var HEIGHT = $gun.css('height').match(/\d*/)[0];

  $('.playground').on('mousemove', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    var mouse = {};

    // your definition of mousemove behavior
    mouse.x = (e.clientX / WIDTH) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = -(e.clientY / HEIGHT) * 2 + 1;

    // your DOM manipulations
    $gun.css('left', mouse.x);
  });
});
```